# Divide collection into parts on laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have this curriculum type of data that should be displayed and unequally divided. See this [image]

What I want is to achieve something like [image: this][image: this]

Here's my code:

StudentController.php

```
public function show($id)
{
    $student = Student::with('course', 'course.curriculum', 'course.curriculum.subjects')->findOrFail($id);

    return view('students.show', compact('student'));
}
```

show.blade.php

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Course Code</th>
                <th>Descriptive Title</th>
                <th>Units</th>
                <th>Prerequisites</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach($student->course->curriculum->subjects as $subject)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $subject->subject_code }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subject->subject_description }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subject->units }}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>98</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: look over collection [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-filter) method

Comment: Does each `Subject` object have a property which indicates which year/semester it's in?

Comment: @BenSwinburne No it does not have.

Comment: So what criteria will decide which table/under which heading a subject should appear?

Comment: @BenSwinburne ah okay yeah I included on which semester.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [`slice()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-slice) method. Example from documentation:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);

$slice = $collection->slice(4);

$slice->all();

// [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```